# OpenCV and textView on top

Tags: android, opencv, surfaceview

I am trying to work on this Android project with openCV. Not much complicated, but rather hand detection and a music player.
I do have basic knowledge about Android, but I am confused with a few things specifically using Surface holder and View.
We started the project using the 'openCV sample- face detection'.. 
Firstly, I want to put Image/TextView on top of the Camera Feed. I do see many threads on this, but I am not sure if the existing code is very different; not sure if its using 'surface view' or not.
So instead of Linear Layout, I changed it to - Relative Layout in the XML. One error I was getting was 'Button cannot be inflated error' 
This is my XML-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_manipulations_activity_surface_view" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:text="Press mee"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_manipulations_activity_surface_view"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDisp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my OnCreate(WITH ERRORS) looks something like this:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.image_manipulations_surface_view);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.image_manipulations_activity_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        //GET REFERENCEE
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.groovy);
        //display current volume
   //     final Button button  = (Button) findViewById(id.button1);

      //  public boolean onTouch
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
      //  View

        ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
        views.add(findViewById(R.id.button1));
        views.add(findViewById(R.id.txtDisp));
        mOpenCvCameraView.addTouchables(views);

        SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.image_manipulations_activity_surface_view);
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(mSurfaceHolderCallback);

    }
```